How do Twitter and messaging apps turn URLs into graphical previews?
If you post a link on Twitter or send it via some messaging apps, they turn the text URL into a pretty graphical preview that the users see before even clicking the link.
How does this work? Does Twitter scan the website on its own? Or does it use some API that the website is expected to provide?

Twitter and the other apps usually do pull metadata from the linked URL to provide a preview. Twitter will look for metatags (either proprietary or Open Graph) in the site's header that will tell it what information and which image to include, but if that information isn't offered Twitter's parser will try to identify it in the page. There are a variety of plugins and extensions for content management systems that will manage this for website owners.
This used to be more transparent on Twitter. There was a tool at https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator that would show anyone how Twitter would display a page. That has now moved into the Tweet Composer tool, as per https://devcommunity.x.com/t/card-validator-preview-removal/175006, so only someone with a Twitter account can see the preview.
There's a similar tool that still works for Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/. The service usually caches a sample of the page the first time it is linked to on the site so that it is not constantly querying the destination site.
